# Избавиться от таймера всплывающего окна

Tags: ассемблер, дизассемблирование, обратная-разработка

В программе всплывает назойливое окно , у которого необходимо убрать  таймер с кнопки окей.То есть, чтобы когда окно очередной раз всплывёт,можно было бы сразу нажать на окей , а не ждать 10 секунд, чтобы можно было нажать на окей и закрыть назойливое окно. Код дизассемблировал и в итоге нашел функцию отвечающую за таймер всплывающего окна

```
.text:00401590 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.text:00401590
.text:00401590
.text:00401590 sub_401590      proc near               ; DATA XREF: .rdata:0040245C↓o
.text:00401590                 push    esi
.text:00401591                 mov     esi, ecx
.text:00401593                 call    ?OnInitDialog@CDialog@@UAEHXZ ; CDialog::OnInitDialog(void)
.text:00401598                 mov     eax, [esi+20h]
.text:0040159B                 push    0               ; lpTimerFunc
.text:0040159D                 push    64h             ; uElapse
.text:0040159F                 push    3               ; nIDEvent
.text:004015A1                 push    eax             ; hWnd
.text:004015A2                 call    ds:SetTimer
.text:004015A8                 push    0               ; int
.text:004015AA                 lea     ecx, [esi+64h]  ; this
.text:004015AD                 mov     dword ptr [esi+60h], 0
.text:004015B4                 call    ?EnableWindow@CWnd@@QAEHH@Z ; CWnd::EnableWindow(int)
.text:004015B9                 mov     eax, 1
.text:004015BE                 pop     esi
.text:004015BF                 retn
.text:004015BF sub_401590      endp
.text:004015BF
.text:004015C0 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:004015C0                 sub     esp, 0Ch
.text:004015C3                 push    esi
.text:004015C4                 mov     esi, ecx
.text:004015C6                 mov     edx, [esi+60h]
.text:004015C9                 inc     edx
.text:004015CA                 mov     eax, edx
.text:004015CC                 mov     [esi+60h], edx
.text:004015CF                 cmp     eax, 64h
.text:004015D2                 jle     short loc_401608
.text:004015D4                 mov     eax, [esi+20h]
.text:004015D7                 push    edi
.text:004015D8                 push    3
.text:004015DA                 push    eax
.text:004015DB                 call    ds:KillTimer
.text:004015E1                 lea     edi, [esi+64h]
.text:004015E4                 push    1
.text:004015E6                 mov     ecx, edi
.text:004015E8                 call    ?EnableWindow@CWnd@@QAEHH@Z ; CWnd::EnableWindow(int)
.text:004015ED                 push    offset unk_403024
.text:004015F2                 mov     ecx, edi
.text:004015F4                 call    ?SetWindowTextA@CWnd@@QAEXPBD@Z ; CWnd::SetWindowTextA(char const *)
.text:004015F9                 pop     edi
.text:004015FA                 mov     ecx, esi
.text:004015FC                 call    ?Default@CWnd@@IAEJXZ ; CWnd::Default(void)
.text:00401601                 pop     esi
.text:00401602                 add     esp, 0Ch
.text:00401605                 retn    4
.text:00401608 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

И еще одно , когда изменяю push 64h на push 0 , то таймер не пропадает, но уменьшается значительно быстрее , но нужно, чтобы таймера сразу не было

Зачем вызывается эта функция

```
loc_401608:                             ; CODE XREF: .text:004015D2↑j
.text:00401608                 mov     ecx, 64h
.text:0040160D                 lea     edx, [esp+4]
.text:00401611                 sub     ecx, eax
.text:00401613                 push    ecx
.text:00401614                 push    offset unk_403020
.text:00401619                 push    edx
.text:0040161A                 call    ds:sprintf
.text:00401620                 add     esp, 0Ch
.text:00401623                 lea     eax, [esp+4]
.text:00401627                 lea     ecx, [esi+64h]
.text:0040162A                 push    eax
.text:0040162B                 call    ?SetWindowTextA@CWnd@@QAEXPBD@Z ; CWnd::SetWindowTextA(char const *)
.text:00401630                 mov     ecx, esi
.text:00401632                 call    ?Default@CWnd@@IAEJXZ ; CWnd::Default(void)
.text:00401637                 pop     esi
.text:00401638                 add     esp, 0Ch
.text:0040163B                 retn    4
.text:0040163B ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:0040163E                 align 10h
.text:00401640                 cmp     dword ptr [ecx+60h], 64h
.text:00401644                 jl      short locret_40164B
.text:00401646                 jmp     ?Default@CWnd@@IAEJXZ ; CWnd::Default(void)
.text:0040164B ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: [CDialog::OnInitDialog](http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/steps/help/r.php?613). Этот код выполняется, когда диалоговое окно уже существует (уже после выполнения конструктора). Вам нужно найти код, который создает диалоговое окно. Нужно копать глубже.

Comment: мне нужно , чтобы диалоговое окно появилось, а таймер в нем не включался , а чтобы сразу можно было нажать окей

Comment: Во втором куске поменяйте `cmp     eax, 64h` на `cmp     eax, 0`, будет завершаться после 100 мс. Или `jle` забить `nop`-ами. По идее.

Comment: можете объяснить , как эта часть работает ?

Comment: 100мс*100 = 10 секунд (те самые 10 секунд из начала вопроса). Во второй части идет сравнение чего-то со 100 (64h), если больше - то KillTimer. Предполагаем, что это как раз то что нужно, патчим - если работает, значит все ок. Я не помню как работает SetTimer/KillTimer, но скорее всего это то что вам нужно.

Comment: Всё! отлично работает , как и надо , спасибо !

Comment: @insolor, а что здесь является счетчиком для этого всплывающего окна  ? Это [esi+20h] ? или это [esi+64h] ,что вообще значит  mov     dword ptr [esi+60h]

Comment: `[esi+60h]`. Тут вот какая фишка: данные функции - это методы какого-то класса. В них через ecx передается указатель на объект, к которому методы применяются, в процессе работы этот указатель "перекладывается" в esi. В объекте видимо отведено поле под счетчик. В первой функции оно инициализируется нулем (`mov     dword ptr [esi+60h], 0`), а во второй функции при каждом ее вызове счетчик увеличивается на единицу (строки с `.text:004015C6` по `.text:004015CC`), потом сравнивается с 100.

Comment: Это сравнение  cmp     eax, 64h ?

Comment: Да, это оно....

Comment: @insolor,а зачем мы заменили jump less equal  на no operation ? что в этой функции проверяется ? И почему мы должны сверять с 100 миллисекунд ?

Comment: я напишу развернутый ответ, но позже (возможно на выходных). Проверяется не 100 миллисекунд, а что прошло 100 циклов по 100 миллисекунд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с документации по функциям WinAPI [`SetTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx) и [`KillTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644903(v=vs.85).aspx).

Вкратце: функция `SetTimer` создает таймер, который заставляет с некоторой периодичностью выполняться какой-то код. Может или посылаться сообщение какому-то окну (в этом случае через параметр `hWnd` в функцию передается идентификатор нужного окна), или вызовом какой-то функции, адрес которой передается через параметр `lpTimerFunc`. В вашем случае в `hWnd` передается "какое-то" значение (очевидно, идентификатор диалогового окна), в `lpTimerFunc` передается 0. Значит будет посылаться сообщение диалоговому окну. Через параметр `uElapse` передается значение 64h (100), это значит, что сообщение окну будет посылаться постоянно, с периодичностью в 100 миллисекунд, пока существует таймер.

Дальше, идет блок кода начиная с адреса `4015C0`. Из приведенного кода этого не видно, но скорее всего это как раз тот код, который обрабатывает сообщение от таймера.

Здесь есть такой код:

```
.text:004015C6                 mov     edx, [esi+60h]
.text:004015C9                 inc     edx
.text:004015CA                 mov     eax, edx
.text:004015CC                 mov     [esi+60h], edx
.text:004015CF                 cmp     eax, 64h
.text:004015D2                 jle     short loc_401608
```

Т.е. с какого-то адреса берется число, увеличивается на 1 (`inc edx`), дальше перекладывается в регистр `eax`, записывается обратно по старому адресу и сравнивается со значением 64h (100 в десятичной системе). Дальше, если согласно результата сравнения получается что число меньше или равно (jle, jump if **lesser or equal**), то происходит переход на метку `loc_401608`. Что по этой метке находится - совсем не интересно, потому что в этом же блоке кода есть вызов функции `KillTimer`, которая прекращает работу таймера (что очевидно из названия), и данный кусок кода (начинающийся с адреса `4015C0`) в дальнейшем уже не будет вызываться.

Чтобы сразу убить таймер, нужно просто убрать переход `jle short loc_401608`. Для этого можно просто "забить" его командами nop (no operation). После данной модификации при первом же вызова блока кода 4015C0, таймер будет сразу же "прибит".

Теперь по поводу задержки. При создании таймера указывается значение 100 (миллисекунд). Соответственно, код обрабатывающий сообщения от таймера, будет вызваться постоянно каждые 100 мс. В самом коде мы видим какой-то счетчик, который первоначально равен 0 (`mov dword ptr [esi+60h], 0` в блоке, где инициализируется таймер), а потом при каждом срабатывании таймера увеличивается на 1, и так пока он не становится больше 100 таймер живет и продолжает посылать сообщения. Отсюда получаем задержку 100 мс * 100 вызовов = 10 000 мс = 10 сек.

Тут, кстати, есть еще один вариант, как убрать задержку - в блоке инициализации таймера заменить `mov dword ptr [esi+60h], 0` например на `mov dword ptr [esi+60h], 100`, тогда при первом же срабатывании таймера счетчик уже будет равен 100, и таймер сразу будет прибит.

Еще вариант - заменить `cmp eax, 64h` на `cmp eax, 0`, результат будет тем же.